# Information related to the sequence, $1,\sqrt{2!},\sqrt[3]{3!},\dots,\sqrt[n]{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, factorial

This question is out of genuine curiosity. There is no reason to believe these numbers have any meaning. I am interested if there is any information related to the sequence,
$$a_n=\sqrt[n]{n!}$$ I encountered the sequence when investigating values of $a$ such that the equation $$x!=a^x$$ has integer solutions. For example, $$x!=(a_5)^x=5!^{x/5}\Rightarrow x=5$$

More generally, where can I consult when I want to find information related to some set of numbers? I've seen [oeis.org](https://oeis.org) but from what I understand they only have information regards to integer sequences, which is not so helpful in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that Stirling's approximation implies $a_n \sim \frac n e$

Answer (score 3):

Using Stirling approximation
$$a_n=\frac ne\left(1+ \frac{\log (2 \pi  n)}{2 n}+\frac{3 \log ^2(2 \pi  n)+2}{24 n^2}+\frac{\log (2 \pi  n) \left(\log ^2(2 \pi  n)+2\right)}{48 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$ is a very good approximation : the relative error is smaller than $1.0$% for $n>1$  and smaller than $0.1$% for $n>4$.

Comment: Have you seen these numbers anywhere else?

Comment: @bob. For this kind of numbers, better to look at the $ISC$

Comment: Thank you, I will check out the ISC.